# understanding the javascript function below and process

Tags: javascript, function

```
function makeAddFunction(amount) {

  function add(number) {

    return number + amount;


  }

  return add;

}

var addTwo = makeAddFunction(2);

var addFive = makeAddFunction(5);

show(addTwo(1) + addFive(1));
```

Comment: That there's some javascript code. Do you have a question about it?

Comment: @AlexWayne can you please explain the  code line by line.Im really confused.

Comment: Which line confuses you? What part do you get and which part don't you get? Edit your question and add some text describing in more detail what you want out of answer.  Try to understand it, at least a little, then ask a question about a specific part you don't get.

Comment: @AlexWayne  Mainly, confused on the last 3 lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`makeAddFunction()` is a function that returns a newly created function. The result is dependent on the `amount` argument passed to `makeAddFunction()`.

```
function makeAddFunction(amount) {
    function add(number) {/*
        We define a function add() that takes 1 argument 
        return number + amount;//The function returns our "number" argument
        plus some "amount", determined by what's passed to makeAddFunction().
        At this stage, you can think of "amount" as a fixed number.
        */
    }
    return add;//We return the add() function, which takes the "number" argument
}

var addTwo = makeAddFunction(2);/*We create a function that takes "number" and
returns "number" + 2. The returned function is exactly the same as: 
function(number){return number + 2;}
*/

var addFive = makeAddFunction(5);/*We create a function that takes "number" and 
returns "number" + 5. The returned function is exactly the same as: 
function(number){return number + 2;)
*/

show(addTwo(1) + addFive(1));//The result is (1 + 2) + (1 + 5) = 9
```

When you write `makeAddFunction(5)`, the interpreter remembers what `amount` is in the given context so the resulting function is equivalent to:

```
function add(number){
    return number + 5;
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) 
I understood everything except the 3 lines. 
How does the addTwo and addFive funciton know to do "number" +2;

Comment: I edited the answer. It should be clear now.

Comment: Thank you. yes it is. I appreciate for explaining it in detail. 
Im new to this. 
So return keyword is same thing as printing on to screen? like console.log? or return just gets the value and just keeps it. 
Any material you recommend on how to think like a software engineer. What to do before start coding? Anything will help.